# PowerTOP: what is "System baseline power"?

Tags: power-management, msi, powertop

I'm running `Ubuntu 13.10` on a `MSI gs70 Stealth` laptop. When I run `powertop 2.4` it tells that (`Device stats` tab):

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 39.8 W
System baseline power is estimated at 23.2 W
```

What does `System baseline power` mean? Isn't it wrong, that it's so big?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it's the minimum power needed by the system.  That is, it's the power that would be used if you were to disable unnecessary hardware like bluetooth and wifi, and turn the screen brightness down.  And 23.2W is not to much.